# Graph API 2.2 and page admins

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to port my application from 1.0 to v2.2 of graph api.
To be specific, I have problems in getting admins of a given page.

Strangely, the endpoint is deprecated while it's not reported like so from docs :

Official doc page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/admins

Actual response in graph api explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) admins is deprecated for versions v2.2 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

Is there any way to have admins ids of a page?

Comment: check out my answer. seems to be a bug in the facebook docs, unfortunately, because it´s only in the changelog.

Comment: correction: actually, it´s just a page that is not linked, the page overview is correct: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The /{page_id}/admins edge on the Page node has been renamed to /v2.2/{page_id}/roles

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thanks! I think that they should declare deprecation in v2.2/page/admins docs.